# What is the width in density (dp) of the WXGA format

Tags: android, titanium

I'm using Titanium to develop an Android/Ipad app. I can't find the exact dp  width of the screen. Unfortunately, I don't have access to low-level API to find it programmatically with the magic formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Titanium.Platform.DisplayCaps](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.7.5/Titanium.Platform.DisplayCaps-object.html)

Comment: Using : `alert(Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.density + "; "+Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi + " ; "+Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth);` I have a medium 160dpi and a width of 1280px, which means I have also 1280 dp.